# Prime numbers and square numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that if $p$ is a prime number such that $p|a^2$, then $p|a$ also, where $a$ is a positive integer.

I expressed a=p1*p2*........pn. Then I squared on both sides. Further I do not know how to move about

Comment: Which of these do you already know: Bezout's Lemma, Euclid's Lemma, Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, or merely the Division Algorithm?

Comment: @BillDubuque Euclid's lemma and fundamental theorem of arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

It is complexer. I proved it indirectly.

If $p \nmid a$, then it isn't in the prime divisors of $a$. So it can't divide also $a^2$.

So if it divides $a^2$, it must divide $a$ as well.

Comment: My comment to Don's answer also applies here.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that if $p|ab$ then $p|a$ or $p|b$ with $b=a$.

You prove this as follows.

If $p$ and $a$ are coprime then we can find integers $x,y$ such that $px+ay=1$. We multiply this by $b$ to get $pbx+aby=b$, and since $p|ab$ it is clear that $p|b$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a=p_1^{a_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n^{a_n}\implies a^2=p_1^{2a_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_n^{2a_n} \implies$$

$$\;p\mid a^2\iff \exists\, i\;\;s.t.\;\;p\mid p_i^{2a_i}=\overbrace{p_i\cdot\ldots\cdot p_i}^{2a_i\;\;\text{times}}\iff p\mid p_i\;\ldots$$

Comment: @OP If you use a proof like this then, to be rigorous and complete, you should *explicitly* mention where you invoke the *existence* and *uniqueness* of prime factorizations, i.e. the *Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic* (or equivalent properties such as Euclid's Lemma).

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the following general statement (which is often called the prime property).

Let $p$ be a prime. If $p$ divides $ab$ then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$.

Idea behind the proof: Suppose $p$ does not divide $a$, then $\gcd(p,a)=1$. Therefore there exists $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that 
$$ax+py=1.$$
Now mulitply by $b$ on both sides and complete the proof.